# How to append values to the custom data stored in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Let's say I want to store some custom value in a element, I would need:

```
$('div').data('k','v');
```

But now I need to add more data to that element: `v2`.

The only way I could come up with is to somehow store or reference the previous data, and append to it, but it doesn't look like the best way to do it nor the most efficient:

```
$('div').data('k','v');
var prevData = $('div').data('k');
$('div').data('k',prevData + ',v2');
alert($('div').data('k'));
```

This will alert `v,v2` as it should, but is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lists as `data` attributes:

```
$('.selector').data('test', []);
var list = $('.selector').data('test');
list.push('foo')
```

It's pretty useful, also because you can fill `data-` attributes with JSON in the HTML at page generation time, and `.data()` will automatically convert them to normal JS objects.

Comment: FYI, from documentation, since jQuery 1.4.3, setting the data extends it. Hence the line `$('.selector').data('test', list);` is not needed, because your `list` already references it.  Reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Sorry for the delay in accepting... I didn't have an Internet connection!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using array as `data` atribute, you can do this

```
$('.selector').data('list', []);
$('.selector').data('list').push(1);
$('.selector').data('list').push(2);
$('.selector').data('list'); // Will return [1,2]
```